# Java: short if else statement

Tags: java, java-8

How to implement the Ternary Operator in this situation ?

```java
Response response = new Response();
if (Objects.equals(message, Const.CONFIRMATION)) {
    response.setMessage(message);
    response.setCodeStatut(Const.HTTP_200);
    response.setNumPolice(c.getNumPolice());
    responseRepository.save(response);
} else(!Objects.equals(message, Const.CONFIRMATION)) {
    response.setMessage(message);
    response.setCodeStatut(Const.HTTP_400);
}

return response;
```

Comment: You don't, because the conditional operator (I suppose you're talking about that specific ternary operator) is meant to return a result, not to call methods that don't return anything.

Comment: So if there are multi expressions inside the if statement we can not implement the shorter form of if else ? what I see is that all the examples are just one expresions inside am I wrong ?

Comment: The conditional operator is meant to be syntactic sugar: `if (foo) { c = a; } else { c = b}` is replaced by `c = foo ? a : b`, where `foo` is or evaluates to a `boolean`, `c` is a variable, and `a` and `b` each evaluate to a value that can be assigned to `c`.  You can nest the conditional operator, but there is a good chance some people will claim it makes your code less readable.

Comment: No, it is not worth it.

Comment: I would in particulr find it very ugly to hide the side effect from `responseRepository.save(response);` inside a ternary operator. Don’t. If you insist, create two methods to create the response in the two cases. Then it’s as simple as `return Objects.equals(message, Const.CONFIRMATION) ? createAndSaveOkResponse(c.getNumPolice()) : createBadRequestResponse(message);`.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is "yes"; you can replace all your code with one (ugly) ternary statement:

```
return Objects.equals(message, Const.CONFIRMATION) ?
    new Response() {{
        setMessage(message);
        setCodeStatut(Const.HTTP_200);
        setNumPolice(c.getNumPolice());
        responseRepository.save(this);
    }} :
    new Response() {{
        setMessage(this);
        setCodeStatut(Const.HTTP_400);
    }};
```

However! Just because you *can* do something, don't mean you *should*. Readability, which includes adherence to convention, is paramount and this code is neither. Further, this implementation suffers from [allowing `this` to escape](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=88487816#content/view/88487816).

In short, *don't try this at home*.

Comment: This is non-idiomatic java code and has problematic side-effects (problematic in that it leads to literally wasting tens to hundreds of developer hours, as the hidden ref to the encompassing instance that this creates results in some garbage no longer being cleaned up). It's borderline __evil__ to post this. It should be downvoted into oblivion. It's not quite 'just run `format c:`' in how pernicious this is, but this kind of advice should not stand as an SO answer.

Comment: @rzwitserloot Thanks for your opinion - I appreciate your frankness. The answer does however answer the question. I have added some cautionary advice.

Comment: Much better. I rescinded my downvote.

Comment: You can easily avoid the problematic anonymous subclasses by just creating two methods to create and set up a `Response` object and using them in a conditional operator.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest not to use ternary operations becasue the code you've written is much more clean and easy to understand comparing to ternary operations for some reason.

- Ternary operations are good, but only for simple conditions
- Writing the code using if/else is easier for the developer to read, and write tests against that code. When using ternary operations, it's usually harder to write good coverage for those branches and you only find out about that when you scan your code using a code coverage tool.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use the ternary operator for this job without doing at least one of:

- Redesigning the API of Response, in which case there are far better things you can do here to clean this code up and make code that uses that class be shorter and simpler.
- Using nasty hacks. As in, seems to work, but can cause extremely serious, many *hours* of wasted time serious effects later on side-effects, and doesn't stack to anything even remotely resembling common code style guidelines.

Hence, don't.

If you'd like this code to be golfed down without resorting to nastiness:

```
var response = new Response();
response.setMessage(message);
response.setCodeStatut(Const.HTTP_400);
if (Const.CONFIRMATION.equals(message)) {
  response.setCodeStatut(Const.HTTP_200);
  response.setNumPolice(c.getNumPolice());
  responseRepository.save(response);
}

return response;
```

- `Objects.equals` is a somewhat dubious tool that can be used if you want to consider `null` to be equal to `null` (that's the dubious part). `Const.CONFIRMATION` surely isn't `null`, or if it is, make that `if (message == null)` instead. Hence, no need for it.
- The `else` clause wouldn't compile, but the intent is clearly just `else`, no need to repeat the negative variant of the same rule.
- Once we're down to that level, `response.setMessage(message)` is always executed, so, you can just do that up top.
- Possibly dubious, but presuming that `setCodeStatut` is a trivial setter, you can just invoke it a second time and avoid the else entirely from there.
- The reason you can't use the ternary operator, is because the ternary operator can only be used with expressions, and a block of statements isn't an expression. There are hacks, but they are just that: Create nasty side-effects, and are so non-standard, they need a hefty comment to explain why no ready alternative will do. That would be a lie, so don't apply the hackery.

Comment: I hate Yoda conditions. If you object to `Objects.equals()` (and I understand your objection), I’d clearly prefer the slightly longer but sparkling clear `message != null && message.equals(Const.CONFIRMATION)`. You may also write your own method with the semantics you want.

Comment: yoda conditions are common enough to make your note a personal beef, which probably isn't relevant to such a simple question (style debates go well beyond what SO is for. Pragmatically speaking, "less than 1% of the java community does this" becomes an objective reason by adding 'programming is a community thing, breaking with the norm has inherent costs' as a notion. Yoda conditions are nothing like that and just pure 'style likes'. OPs question is about, essentially, golfing. Inherently they'd hate your proposed style.

Comment: This reminds me again, how different developers are. I’d use `message.equals(Const.CONFIRMATION)` because I *want* to bail out when `message` is `null`. Does `response.setMessage(message)` work with `null`? I don’t want to think about it, so not letting `message` ever be `null` in the first place is the way to go. Anyway, I’d also avoid calling `setCodeStatut` twice. Using `else response.setCodeStatut(Const.HTTP_400);` is only one additional word…

Comment: [Yoda conditions - criticism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions#Criticism). It’s not *only* a personal beef.

Comment: @Holger Not that different; I treat `null` the same way SQL treats it (unknown value), i.e. I want the NPEs. More NPEs more better. Then I know what to fix. I shoot down `if (x == null || x.isEmpty())` all the time in code review. However, Someone asked an SO question. That is rarely the right time to start tossing personal taste around, and in the rare case that it is - objective reasoning needs to be supplied.

Comment: i.e. _I_ rarely use yoda conditions just to 'integrate' the "false-if-null" aspect of what OP wants, because I rarely want "false-if-null". However, OP does want that, and given that the question isn't about null handling, chiming with 'oh no your null handling is bad' is well beyond the scope. And here we are holding a debate in comments about something __utterly__ unrelated to the question. If someone asks something like "How do more easily treat null as any other value", I can see writing an answer that questions the entire mindset belying that question, but this isn't that question.

Comment: @OleVV every non-trivial programming concept has a page somewhere on the internet with criticisms as long as my leg. That doesn't prove anything. Insofar that you truly feel that it does, go tell the java community to accept 'yoda bad' so deeply that linters and IDEs ship __out of the box__ with linting rules turned on to warn about it, and then I will gladly edit this answer, I don't really like em either.

Comment: I wouldn’t be sure about the OP’s intention. The fact that the original code uses `Objects.equals(…)` doesn’t prove that a null-safe check is intended, there are too many examples overusing these methods (and similarly the awful StringUtils classes, etc.), without the author even being aware of the differences. The question’s code isn’t even valid and the original question “How to implement the Ternary Operator in this situation” doesn’t make sense…

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the ternary operator to call void methods, but you can drop the second conditional check and just use `else`. After all, if `Objects.equals(message, Const.CONFIRMATION)` is `false`, then it is clear that `!Objects.equals(message, Const.CONFIRMATION)` is true.

```java
if (Objects.equals(message, Const.CONFIRMATION)) {
    response.setMessage(message);
    response.setCodeStatut(Const.HTTP_200);
    response.setNumPolice(c.getNumPolice());
    responseRepository.save(response);
} else {
    response.setMessage(message);
    response.setCodeStatut(Const.HTTP_400);
}
```

Comment: I just added what it'll return

Comment: @BAKHALEDIbrahim Ternary operator still doesn't help here unless you have a builder for `Response`.

Comment: So we can not implmeent the shorter form in multi-expressions ?

Comment: @BAKHALEDIbrahim No, you can't.

Comment: Oh I see, every example of the ternary operator are using only one expression so I thought it'll work for the multi expressions but Thanks alot @Unmitigated

Comment: You could *almost* do `response.setMessage(message); response.setCodeStatut(Objects.equals(message, Const.CONFIRMATION) ? Const.HTTP_200 : Const.HTTP_400);` you still have two other statements on only one of the logical branches.

Answer (score 0):

You *could* do this with a helper function:

```
    static Response myFunc() {
        Response response = new Response();
        if (Objects.equals(message, Const.CONFIRMATION)) {
            return createResponse(message, Const.HTTP_200, r -> {
                r.setNumPolice(c.getNumPolice());
                responseRepository.save(r);
            });
        } else {
            return createResponse(message, Const.HTTP_400, r -> {});
        }

        return response;
    }

    static Response createResponse(String message, int status, Consumer<Response> sideEffects) {
        Response response = new Response();
        response.setMessage(message);
        response.setStatus(status);
        sideEffects.accept(response);
        return response;
    }
```

and with the helper function and a ternary operator:

```
        static Response myFunc() {
        return Objects.equals(message, Const.CONFIRMATION)
                ? createResponse(message, Const.HTTP_200, r -> {
                        r.setNumPolice(c.getNumPolice());
                        responseRepository.save(r);
                    })
                : createResponse(message, Const.HTTP_400, r -> {});
        }
```

The advantage of this approach is that you can't forget to set the `message` or the `status`, and the specific other operations you do to the response are kept collected in a single block.

Perhaps this introduces too much extra cognitive load when you read the code, and perhaps in this implementation it is too easy to bypass `createResponse` when you are maintaining the code, but in general creating a small function to remove duplication and to make it easier for developers to follow conventions (or patterns for the use of particular classes) is useful.

As others have said, redesigning `Response` would be a good idea, but if it was a third party class something like this approach would be useful.